# How to move data from sorted to unsorted JSON file?

Tags: json, sublimetext3, text-editor

I have two big JSON files, one of them is sorted alphabetically, and the second one is not. I want to move data from sorted one, to unsorted. How can I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want the data sorted?

The JSON Specification (JSON RFC (RFC 4627)) says that key order is not important. Most implementations of JSON will order them in the most memory efficient way.

If you really need to output them in a sorted, indented format (perhaps for a human to be able to read them) you'll have to use some kind of programming language (perhaps python) to loop over your data, sort the data how you want and then output it to a text file.

But to reiterate: the key ordering of JSON shouldn't matter to any well-behaved software.

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing your files locally, and using Sublime Text - you can easily cut and paste yourself to concatenate or merge these 2 files. Just delete the opening { and ending } brackets from the file you are cutting and pasting from. The paste the contents of the 2nd file inside the closing bracket } of the first file, after inserting a comma right before your pasted data.

If you don't care about the order of this data, that would be your easiest solution. But if you want it to look like your "Expected Result" - you'd have to use Javascript or Python to output the data from the 2nd file with the fields in the same order as the first file.